# DHT-sensor-library-master

Tags: arduino-due, adafruit

I only uploaded the library to check whether it has installed correctly. It's installed and i am having this error. ****Using library DHT-sensor-library-master at version 1.4.1 in folder: C:\Users\Mcniven\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DHT-sensor-library-master\DHT_U.h:36:29: fatal error: Adafruit_Sensor.h: No such file or directory**
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.**

Comment: Did you install the Adafruit_Sensor.h library?

Comment: Did you install the library by just copying it to the “libraries” folder without checking dependencies (looks like it) or did you install it from the Arduino IDE?